# How to monitor IP allocation in Azure subnet?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm

I need to find the current usage of IP addresses within subnets in Azure. I found free IPs in Virtual Networks->subnets but the number is the total available IP addresses within the subnet. How can I see how many of the available IPs within the subnet are actually in use (how many of them are free)? Is there a way to set the monitoring for free IP addresses (or used IP addresses) for Azure subnets?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the [listUsage API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/virtual-networks/list-usage) `/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/aoprod9574-stamp-canadacentral-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-name/usages?api-version=2021-02-01` to get the current allocations per Subnet in a VNet

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "currentValue": 3,
      "id": "/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/aoprod9574-canadacen-vnet/subnets/cosmosdb-pe-snet",
      "limit": 27,
      "name": {
        "localizedValue": "Subnet size and usage",
        "value": "SubnetSpace"
      },
      "resourceGroup": "my-rg",
      "unit": "Count"
    },
    {
      "currentValue": 93,
      "id": "/subscriptions/****/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/aoprod9574-canadacen-vnet/subnets/kubernetes-snet",
      "limit": 1019,
      "name": {
        "localizedValue": "Subnet size and usage",
        "value": "SubnetSpace"
      },
      "resourceGroup": "my-rg",
      "unit": "Count"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Are you maybe aware of an option to monitor IP address usage in Azure in order to create an alert when any IP subnet is out of free IP addresses?

Comment: nope. But you could easily achieve this by regularly running an Azure Function which polls the above API

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if that’s the case